# On which datasets does AdaBoost algorithm overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, overfitting, adaboost

I know that AdaBoost algorithm is less prone to overfitting but I'm curious on which kind of datasets will AdaBoost produce overfitting and why?

Comment: Less prone than which other algorithms? Be specific and put in reference.

Answer (score 1):

AdaBoost is quite robust to overfitting, and LPBoost (Linear Programming Boosting) even more so (because the objective function requires a sparse combination of weak learners, which is a form of capacity control). The main factors that influence it are:

- The "strength" of the "weak" learners: If you use very simple weak
  learners, such as decision stumps (1-level decision trees), then the
  algorithms are much less prone to overfitting. Whenever I've tried
  using more complicated weak learners (such as decision trees or even
  hyperplanes) I've found that overfitting occurs much more rapidly
- The noise level in the data: AdaBoost is particularly prone to
  overfitting on noisy datasets. In this setting the regularised forms
  (RegBoost, AdaBoostReg, LPBoost, QPBoost) are preferable
- The dimensionality of the data: We know that in general, we
  experience overfitting more in high dimensional spaces ("the curse of
  dimensionality"), and AdaBoost can also suffer in that respect, as it
  is simply a linear combination of classifiers which themselves suffer
  from the problem. Whether it is as prone as other classifiers is hard
  to determine.

Of course you can use heuristic methods such as validation sets or kk-fold cross-validation to set the stopping parameter (or other parameters in the different variants) as you would for any other classifier.